# What is a single word for "to completely root out a disease"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Please tell the single word for "to completely root out a disease".

Comment: A second option is *expunge*, but *eradicate* is probably the more commonly used term. Especially if referring to a population, and not just one person. https://www.asm.org/index.php/newsroom/item/5699-could-camel-antibodies-protect-humans-from-mers

Comment: Eradicate. The only diseases to have been completely eradicated are smallpox in people and rinderpest in cattle. I hope to live to see the eradication of polio.

Comment: @Princess Anne: Do you want to convey that the disease was completely removed from a person or is the intention to convey that the person certainly does not have a particular disease?

Comment: To me, the answer would be *diagnose*.  I see no connection between *root out* and *cure*.

Comment: @Chenmunka *Root out* means "to find and remove", which if one it's talking about a disease, would definitely connect to *cure*. *Diagnose*, on the other hand, simply means "identify the nature (of an illness or other problem) by examination of the symptoms". That's a totally different thing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'root out'? A single person who had the disease does not have it at all anymore? Or do you mean of a group of people, no one has the disease? Can you elaborate?

Comment: None of the answers so far mean "to completely root out a disease". All of the answers below mean "to completely root out".

Comment: In the IT field, "Nuke" is appropriate :)

Comment: @Princess Anne, can you include information on how it will be used?

Comment: @JulianCienfuegos I don't think there is a single word in English that combines all those concepts ('completely' and 'rooting out' and 'disease'). It is reasonable then to come up with a word that is used in the context of the others (namely just 'rooting out') with qualification as to what the context really is.

Comment: You can use 'obviate'. It means that the problem is gone, and no further remedy is required. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obviate. Eg the cure has obviated the need for further treatment.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Eradicate**.

[Etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology)  is from Eradicare. 
Eradicare, in turn, can be traced back to the Latin word radix, meaning "root" or "radish." Although **eradicate** began life as a word for literal uprooting, by the mid-17th century it had developed a [metaphorical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphors) application to removing things.

Ref: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eradicate

**Eradication** is the reduction of an infectious disease's prevalence in the global host population to zero.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eradication_of_infectious_disease

Comment: **Eradication** is the word used to describe the complete elimination of Smallpox in the World Health Organisation's statements on the disease, which I think is as close as you can get to an absolutely authoritative statement on the subject: http://www.who.int/mediacentre/news/notes/2010/smallpox_20100517/en/

Answer (score 9):

You just touched on a common confusion, that between **'eliminate'** and **'eradicate'**. They are almost identical (besides nuanced collocations and frequencies).

In the context of disease, both are used for the state where no one has a particular it anymore.  But [the American CDC has stipulated definitions to contrast some important situations.](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/preview/mmwrhtml/su48a7.htm)

They define a set of words in ever declining prevalence:

- control - prevalence has been restricted to an acceptable level
- **elimination** of disease - the disease does not occur _in a given restricted geological area. For example, polio has been eliminated from Canada (no one currently has the disease polio there), but there are still instances of polio in India
- elimination of infection - no one in a geographic area has shown positive tests for the organism (implying no disease *and* no likelihood of it starting back up again)
- **eradication** - no one on Earth anywhere has evidence of the organism (may exist in a lab)
- extinction - the infectious agent no longer exists on Earth at all. For example, smallpox has been eradicated (it is not out in the wild but there are some vials of it in highly secure labs).

Note that these are officially sanctioned technical uses. In informal conversation, either would be understood that 'no one gets that disease anymore and it can't come back'. But on the news or in a journal article or in science reporting eliminate refers to a particular location and eradicate refers to the whole world.

Answer (score 5):

**Extirpate**

For example, the New York Times 08 April 1923 [quotes](https://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/%22extirpation+of+defective+stocks+%22/) ever-controversial Margaret Sanger:

> Birth Control is not contraception indiscriminately and thoughtlessly practiced. It means the release and cultivation of the better racial elements in our society, and the gradual suppression, elimination and eventual extirpation of defective stocks — those human weeds which threaten the blooming of the finest flowers of American civilization.

Answer (score 2):

*purge* can also be used in this context, and is more visceral that either *eradicate* or *extirpate*.

Comment: In a medical context, _purge_ means "vomit".

Comment: Or in medicine, it can [mean:](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/purge) to cause a copious evacuation of the bowels

Answer (score 1):

Although *eradicate* is clearly the right word -- even etymologically, as it derives from *radix*, root -- I prefer *extirpate*.  Although its origin in *stirps*, "stem", perhaps casts it as less thorough than eradication, in the words of Bender Rodriguez, "the X makes it sound cool."

**Edit:** a commenter informs us that in this case, the etymology is accurate: at least in technical contexts, something eradicated is removed from existence, root and branch; something extirpated merely has suffered a local stem to be pruned.

But I stand by my choice, on euphonic grounds.  The "x" and then the crisp "p" make it sound even more devastating than "exterminate".

Comment: -1. Extirpation is a synonym for local extinction, it does not mean the same thing as eradicate, no matter how cool it sounds.

Comment: @AlexanderDunlap : "`extirpate`": "to destroy or remove (something) completely" (Merriam Webster);  "eradicate or destroy completely." (Oxford Dictionaries). Just saying.

Comment: Given the word's technical sense in ecology, I would think that using it in reference to disease in this way would be confusing at best. But fair enough, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @AlexanderDunlap This 1901 dictionary https://books.google.com/books?id=z8hWAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA1687&dq=extirpate+from+earth&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXuMrgifXTAhWD2SYKHetqCpwQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=extirpate%20from%20earth&f=false has a note saying that another work,"Crabb", makes a distinction between extirpate and eradicate; but the dictionary itself doesn't seem to adopt the distinction.

Comment: @AlexanderDunlap From 1849 there is "When God determined to extirpate from the earth, the wicked and abominable generation who had polluted it, and whose crimes cried to heaven for vengeance, he resolved to save Noah and his family", so the completely eliminate meaning has been around for a long time https://books.google.com/books?id=Ef0IAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA29&dq=%22extirpate+from+the+earth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF0vTpjPXTAhVLLyYKHTklBy4Q6AEIRjAG#v=onepage&q=%22extirpate%20from%20the%20earth%22&f=false

Comment: The original question was applying a word to a disease, though, which means that the definition from ecology would likely come to mind for readers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the disease's cause (A virus, bacterium or other living creature):

*Exterminate* might be a more fitting phrase.